# "Roots" of Unity for the General Linear Group?

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, group-theory, general-linear-group

I was watching the [Michael Penn video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R-eCUwhnO8c) about representations when he demonstrated a few matrices that when squared equal the identity (all of them below).
[image]

These were mostly easy because I could visualize moving the unit vectors around in my head, but I was wondering if there was a general way to find the "roots of unity" for matrices of arbitrary dimension and of degree (for example, I don't know how to find all the matrices in GL(3) that have order 3). Thank you for reading and have a nice day :)

Comment: For small cases, you can use a computer to solve the system of equations $\{ \sum_{k=1}^n x_{i,k}x_{k,j} \ | \ 1 \leq i,j \leq n\}$, where $n$ is the dimension of the matrix. I don't know a general method though, but maybe it can help you find one!